# Assign unique id to directive attribute from link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my AngularJS app, I have a shopping cart directive where I need to assign a unique id from the directives link method to the `id` attribute whilst setting the value of the other attributes  from the exposed controller.

*Directive*

```
.directive('ngcartAddtocart', ['ngCart', function(ngCart){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        controller : 'CartController',
        scope: {
            id: '=',
            name:'@',
            price:'@',
            data:'='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link:function(scope, element, attrs){

            var ID = (function () {
                return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
            }())

            attrs.id = ID;

        }
}])
```

*View*

```
<ngcart-addtocart 
    id="" <!--THIS I WANT TO DYNAMICALLY ADD ID FROM DIRECTIVE -->
    name="item.name" <!-- PROVIDED BY CONTROLLER -->
    price="item.price" <!-- PROVIDED BY CONTROLLER -->
    data="object.data" <!-- PROVIDED BY CONTROLLER -->
></ngcart-addtocart>
```

***Question***

What is the best way to dynamically add the ID to the directive from the directives link method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.attr("id",ID);`

```
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){

        var ID = (function () {
            return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
        }())

        ̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶.̶i̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶I̶D̶;̶
        element.attr("id",ID);
    }
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)